# Lightning Glow not Rendering

Tags: rendering

I am trying to render lightning to my scene, but for some reason on the viewer the "glow" shows up (left pic), but after I render the glow completely disappears and looks completely flat.

I have no idea why this is happening...

[image]

Comment: Figured it out! You need to add a glare node in order for it to show up in the final render!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.